# Aux pattern not working for nested implicits

Tags: scala, functional-programming, aux-pattern

I have the following `Types`

```scala
sealed trait Types

object Types {
  case class A(value: Int) extends Types

  case class B(value: String, flag: Boolean) extends Types

  case class L(value: Types, n: Int) extends Types
}
```

I want to have a `generate` method that will generate an output based on the input type, and the output might have different types. I tried to use the Aux pattern and for type `A` and type `B` the values are generated.

```scala
trait Generate[In] {
  type Out

  def generate(in: In): Out
}

object Generate {

  type Aux[I, O] = Generate[I] {type Out = O}

  implicit object AGenerate extends Generate[Types.A] {
    override type Out = Int

    override def generate(a: Types.A): Out = a.value
  }

  implicit object BGenerate extends Generate[Types.B] {
    override type Out = String

    override def generate(b: Types.B): Out = if (b.flag) b.value else "nope"
  }

//  implicit def lGenerate[T, O](implicit aux: Aux[T, O]): Generate[Types.L] = new Generate[Types.L] {
//    override type Out = List[O]
//
//    override def generate(in: Types.L): Out = List.fill(in.n)(aux.generate(in.value))
//  }

  implicit class RichGenerator[I](in: I) {
    def generate[O](implicit aux: Aux[I, O]): O = aux.generate(in)
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  import Types._
  import Generate._

  val a = A(1)
  val b = B("yep", flag = true)

  println(a.generate) // prints 1: Int
  println(b.generate) // prints "yep": String
}
```

However, when I try to generate a value for type `L`, which depends on `Types`, then the implicit resolution fails.

My goal is to obtain the following outputs:

```scala
println(L(a, 3).generate) \\ prints List(1,1,1)
println(L(b, 2).generate) \\ prints List("yep", "yep")
println(L(L(a,3), 2).generate) \\ prints List(List(1,1,1), List(1,1,1))
```

Comment: `implicit def lGenerate[T, O](implicit aux: Aux[T, O]): Generate[Types.L]` indicate no connection between `T`, `O` and `Types.L`. As a matter of the fact - `Types.L` contains `Types`, which means that it upcast and makes you loose any detailed information about its content. You'd would need to change the type `Types` so that nested values would still somehow preserve the type information about the content and then reflect it on the implicits and Aux pattern.

Comment: Looks great, thank you! Please provide it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to properly link the `Aux` types together.

First, let's make `L` generic:

```scala
final case class L[T <: Types](value: T, n: Int) extends Types
```

Then, let's properly define its `Generator` instance:

```scala
implicit def lGenerate[T <: Types, O](implicit aux: Aux[T, O]): Aux[Types.L[T], List[O]] =
  new Generate[Types.L[T]] {
    override type Out = List[O]
  
    override def generate(in: Types.L[T]): Out =
      List.fill(in.n)(aux.generate(in.value))
  }
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/p4ACzrOhQdOu0diwBQzbHg/2).*